# Calling variable names by textfield

Tags: swift, class, variables

I would like to show class values on a `textfield` in Swift. In my example I have a `class` with two instances as shown below. I then have a scene with a `textfield`, `label`, and `button`. On the `textField` I would like to type the instance name - like "chevy" and on clicking the `button` show an attribute of my instance on a `label`.

```
class Auto {
    var make:String
    var model:String
    var color:String

    init(make: String, model: String, color: String){
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
    }
}

var chevy = Auto(make: "Chevrolet", model: "HHR", color: "Blue")
var prius = Auto(make: "Toyota", model: "Prius", color: "white")
```

My attempt to accomplish this  have tried:

```
var carType: String
carType = txtMyCar.text!
carType = "prius"

lblShow.text = carType.color
```

This obviously does not work. How can I show the variable "color" by having the textbook with the instance name?

Comment: Why don't you add a `name` attribute in `Auto` and give them respective `chevy` or `prius` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `type` attribute to your `class Auto` and use that to get the attribute values, i.e.

```
enum CarType: String {
    case chevy, prius
}

class Auto {
    let make:String
    let model:String
    let color:String
    let type: CarType

    init(make: String, model: String, color: String, type: CarType){
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

You can use it like,

```
let chevy = Auto(make: "Chevrolet", model: "HHR", color: "Blue", type: .chevy)
let prius = Auto(make: "Toyota", model: "Prius", color: "white", type: .prius)
```

Next, you can get the `CarType` from text in `textField` using `CarType's` `init(rawValue:)` like so,

```
if let text = txtMyCar.text {
    let carType = CarType(rawValue: text)
    lblShow.text = carType?.color
}
```

Comment: Thank you PGDev, and I am getting an error message "Value of type 'CarType?' has no member 'color'. How would I fix that?

Comment: Use `carType?.color`

Comment: Even with carType?.color I get  the warning "Value of type 'CarType?' has no member 'color'" My class file is exactly as you have it here

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

What you can do is to create an array of cars

```
let cars = [Auto(make: "Chevrolet", model: "HHR", color: "Blue"),
            Auto(make: "Toyota", model: "Prius", color: "white")]
```

and when you type `chev` and press the button you can filter the array with

```
if let car = cars.first(where: {$0.make.range(of: txtMyCar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive}) != nil {
   lblShow.text = car.color
}
```